# How to fetch perticular column data of table?

Tags: extension

Currently I am using API for fetch the data.
I am creating an extension.
I want to fetch the particular column's data from the table. How will I get the data?

```
//getting id and name
public static function getName(){
 $data = ($id,$name);
  $result = civicrm_api3('Emp', 'get', [
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => ["id", "name"],
  ]);

  foreach ($result['values'] as $value) {
      $data[$id] += $value['id'];
      $data[$name] += $value['name'];

  }
  return $data;
}
```

> Select option using BuildQuickForm

```
$this->add('select', 
      'name',         //field type 
      'name', //field label
      $this->getName() //list (id, name) 
      );
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For every table CiviCRM has api, you can use following method to retrieve data by specifying **return** in api params.

1 - **Get** -  Returns one or more results and with N number of columns

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', [
  'return' => ["id", "display_name"],
  'contact_sub_type' => "Parent",
]);
```

2 - **GetValue** - Returns only single result and with single column (make sure to use id in filer or limit =1 else the api will throw error if the api returns more than one results)

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getvalue', [
  'return' => "display_name",
  'id' => 1,
]);
```

3 - **GetSingle** - Returns only single result and with N number of columns (make sure to use id in filer or limit =1 else the api will throw error if the api returns more than one results)

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', [
  'return' => ["display_name", "email"],
  'id' => 1,
]);
```

Incase if you want to retrieve from custom table created using extension then you will need to make sure you have

1. New entity defined -
2. DAO for the table
3. api with create, delete and get action

You can use [Civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity) to create new entity which will create above 3 points automatically for you.

Then you can use below snippet to build your select field

```
    $this->add('select', 
      'name',         //field type 
      ts('Name'), //field label
      CRM_Utils_Array::collect('name', civicrm_api3('Emp', 'get', [
        'return' => ["id", "name"],
      ])['values']) //list (id, name) 
    );
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I have an id and user_name columns in table. I want to fetch and put as option value i.e. <option value='id'>user_name </option>

Comment: Which table you talking about? Is it a civi table or your own table?

Comment: My custom table. Check the above image.

Comment: Updated my answer to include your case

Comment: I create a module using civix. Please refer edited question.

Comment: So do you have Emp api defined?

Comment: Yes Sir. DAO BAO and API. I fetch that value Using CiviCRM API 3, .

Comment: Updated the answer, please check!

Comment: Thanks Sir. But how this code is working? I am not understanding.

Comment: You can get idea how this works at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Array.php#L613 . So can you please mark this as answered my answer solves your problem?

Comment: I already marked as true answer.

Comment: I think you voted up rather marking it as answered

Comment: Both voted as well as marked.